# When is $\ln x = x^{\frac13}$?

Tags: logarithms

[image]

When is $\ln x = x^{\frac13}$?

Is there any way to find this solution that isn't just an estimate?

--

Wolfram says it has to do with lambert functions? How do I get in to those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that 
\begin{align*}
\ln x &= x^{1/3}\implies\\
x &= \exp(x^{1/3})\implies\\
x^{1/3} &= \exp(x^{1/3}/3)\implies\\
-\frac{x^{1/3}}{3}\exp\left(-\frac{x^{1/3}}{3}\right) &= -\frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}

Since the Lambert $W$ function is defined as the inverse of $xe^x$, we find:

$$-\frac{x^{1/3}}{3}=W\left(-\frac13\right)$$

so then

$$x = -27\, W^3\left(-\frac13\right)$$

Note that this actually contains two solutions, using the different branches of the $W$ function.

Comment: (+1) Our final answers are the same, but we used the relation $we^w=x$ to rewrite $x$ at different points.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Argon's answer, though the path is a bit different

If $\log(x)=x^{1/3}$, then
$$
x^{-1/3}\log\left(x^{-1/3}\right)=-\frac13
$$
Thus, if we let $u=\log\left(x^{-1/3}\right)$, then
$$
u\,e^u=-\frac13
$$
Therefore,
$$
x=e^{-3u}=-27u^3=-27\operatorname{W}\!\left(-\frac13\right)^3
$$
There are two real branches of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) for negative arguments. These give the two solutions
$$
x=6.4056720789810570276
$$
and
$$
x=93.354460835003657851
$$

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you get anything nicer. Maple yielded two solutions:
$6.4056720789810570272$ and $93.354460835003657852$
I fed these into the https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc
and it found nothing. I guess it remains for you to learn more
about LambertW,
starting with, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Lambert function and still look for the solution(s) of equation $$\log(x) = x^{\frac13}$$ consider that you look for the zero(s) of function
$$f(x)=\log(x) - x^{\frac13}$$ $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3 x^{2/3}}$$ 
$$f''(x)=\frac{2}{9 x^{5/3}}-\frac{1}{x^2} $$The first derivative cancels when $x=27$ and $f(27)=\log (27)-3\approx 0.295837$, $f''(27)=-\frac{1}{2187}$.

So, $x=27$ corresponds to a maximum and then the equation shows two roots. Graphing would show that the roots are "close" to $5$ and $100$. So, you have your starting points for Newton method. It should provide the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 5.000000000 \\
 1 & 6.169025112 \\
 2 & 6.398944686 \\
 3 & 6.405666633 \\
 4 & 6.405672079
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 100.0000000 \\
 1 & 93.34450012 \\
 2 & 93.35446083 \\
 3 & 93.35446084
\end{array}
\right)$$ which are the solutions for ten significant figures.